# How to send the errors in Action(Redux) to the Frontend(React)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

So I am building a MERN stack application that does have a login functionality. Whenever the user sends the wrong credentials, I am throwing an error through `res.json({errorMessage: 'sample'})`. However, I also implemented Redux in my application and I have an action that looks like this.

```
export const loginUser =
  ({ email, password }) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/auth/login", {
        email,
        password,
      });

      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_USER", payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Err", error.response.data.errorMessage);
    }
  };
```

I am getting the errorMessage here in the actions but I want to display it in React. I am trying to access it in this way but it doesn't work.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      dispatch(loginUser({ email, password }));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data.errorMessage);
    }
  };
```

I am getting the error in the action and not in my frontend. How can I get the errorMessage in my frontend? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add throw error in the catch of `loginUser`

```
export const loginUser =
  ({ email, password }) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/auth/login", {
        email,
        password,
      });

      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_USER", payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Err", error.response.data.errorMessage);
      throw error
    }
  };
```

And change `handleSubmit` to `async`

```
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      await dispatch(loginUser({ email, password }));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data.errorMessage);
    }
  };
```

Comment: I added it but unfortunately, it's giving me an error.

Comment: omg it worked!! Thanks for helping. I really appreciate it!